# Bottom overflowed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code that is responsible for displaying the characteristics of the device (the code is presented below. I have shortened it for readability.)
My problem:

1. in the body: if there are long names, then the display of elements is confused (as in the photo). How can I get the elements to display correctly even with long titles?
2. in appbar: how can I make the text size of the device name change depending on the size of the text itself (so that the name of the device can be seen in full)

   ```
        return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(device.name),
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
            color: Colors.black,
            iconSize: 40.0,
            onPressed: () {}
        ),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white, size: 40),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.phonelink_setup, size: 40.0,),
            color: Colors.black,
            onPressed: () {}),],
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800, maxHeight: 400),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),),
                      child: Card(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                                title: const Text('Brand:'),
                                trailing: Text('${device.brand}')),
                            const Divider(color: Colors.black, endIndent: 10, indent: 10),
                            ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
              ]
                  )
            )
        )
    );
      }
   ```

   }

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) widget! For your example, if you want to resize your AppBar text based on width.

```
appBar: AppBar(
          title: const FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            child: Text('Very very veryveryvery veryveryvery longname'),
          ),
        ),
```

Then, your text size will be adjusted accordingly. You can do the same with the device name.

Another option for you for the device name might be using `overflow` and `softwrap` to make it multiple lines without adjusting the font size.

```
 appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            'Very very veryveryvery veryveryvery longname',
            overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
            softWrap: true,
          ),
        ),
```

You may look at the `BoxFit` options here.

There is another option that you can use which is [Auto_Text_Size](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text). It's a very nice package and works very well!

Comment: thank you. AppBarr work good. But  it not fix problem in body

Comment: It seems in the body you still need to have your widget with wrapped inside a fixed width so that it doesn’t push it. Use fitted box it should most likely help

Answer (score 0):

you can fix the overflow by wrapping the listTile inside another single scroll

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).